# How can I typeset a break or jump in my scores?

Tags: notation, lilypond

I am using lilypond to typeset some music. I would like to leave away some bars from the original music. Therefore, I have to jump from some bar to an other. But I want to show, that I cut something out.

What is the most common notation for such thing and how could I achieve that with lilypond?

- The score stops at rehearsal mark A at bar 100
- Some notation like "jump to", a symbol, an arrow, [...], blank bars...
- The score begins again at rehearsal mark M at bar 200
- The bar numbering starting at rehearsal mark M shout be 200 (100) | 201 (101) | 202 (102) | and so on.

Maybe, there is something in the manual for lilypond, but I can not find it. I don't even remember the Italian expression for "jump to".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Bar Numbers](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.17/Documentation/notation/bars#bar-numbers)  and [Rehearsal Marks](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.17/Documentation/notation/bars#rehearsal-marks)  segments of the documentation indicate how to do this:

```
c1 | c1 | c1 | c1
%location where music has been elided

% I'd do something like:
s1^"2nd Movement Deleted" | s1 | s1 | s1 \break
% which inserts a line of blank bars, with a comment above 
% indicating what has been removed

%reset the bar-number counter to the bar number that you want
\set Score.currentBarNumber = #200
\mark #13 % insert a rehearsal mark corresponding to "M" (letter 13)
c1 | c1 | c1 | c1
\mark \default %subsequent rehearsal marks will increment \
               %from the previous (this will be "N").
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that at home. Two more things: Do you now, how to say "jump to M" in Italian (or French. I am looking for some expression like "vi de". Can't remember the real words). And do you know, how to do a double numeration of the bars "old number (new number)"?

Comment: Interesting-- reference pages like the Dolmetsch page of notations have the "jump to Coda" but no other item to mark a cut or skip.

Comment: Yes, this would be cool, to have an item for that. But the blank bar looks fine for now.

Comment: http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.17/Documentation/notation/bars#bar-lines There is a type of bar line which yields a "[". Would look nice I think, but I don't succeed.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi this might be new for 2.17; are you using an earlier version?

Comment: yes. 2.16.0 I will have to wait then

Comment: "\mark #13" prints an "N" and not an "M". 
This is because engraving tradition skips the letter "I".

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for "" (the Segno), and "D.S." (Dal Segno).  "Dal Segno" is Italian for "From the Sign", where as "" is the sign.

These are instructions used in musical scores for jumps (although usually for jumping backwards).  A similar symbol is the coda symbol "".  There are also a handful of related phrases (in Italian) for jumping around in a score.

---

Implementation with a LilyPond score is reasonably straight forward, but as you are actually skipping a section, and using the rehearsal marks it takes a bit of a fiddle:

```
\score {
    \new Staff {
        \set Score.currentBarNumber = #92
            e'1 | e'1 | e'1 | e'1 |
                \break

            g'1 | g'1 | g'1 | g'1 _\markup{ \bold "( D.S. )"} |
                    \bar "||"

        \stopStaff
        \cadenzaOn
            \mark \default
            s1 
        \cadenzaOff
        \startStaff
            \bar ""
            \break

        \set Score.currentBarNumber = #200
        \mark #12
            b'1 ^\markup {( \musicglyph #"scripts.segno" )} | b'1 | b'1 | b'1 |
    }
}
```

[image: 99DS A100 S200]

N.B.  I could not figure out how to customise the bar numbers to have "200 (100)" etc.